# How I can open the "ExpandableListView" on new Activity when click on ImageView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've created **ExpandableListView** that is shown first when you run the app.

But now I have created another activity with ImageView to be the main page of the app. I don't want the **ExpandableListView** to be the first shown -  only to show after click on the ImageView. How I can do that?

Here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    List<String> chapterList;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> topicList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.eListView);
        showList();
        listViewAdapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(this, chapterList, topicList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

    }

    private void showList() {

        chapterList = new ArrayList<String>();
        topicList =   new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        chapterList.add("Chapter 1");
        chapterList.add("Chapter 2");
        chapterList.add("Chapter 3");
        chapterList.add("Chapter 4");
        chapterList.add("Chapter 5");

        List<String> topic1 = new ArrayList<>();
        topic1.add("Topic 1");
        topic1.add("Topic 2");
        topic1.add("Topic 3");

        List<String> topic2 = new ArrayList<>();
        topic2.add("Topic 1");
        topic2.add("Topic 2");
        topic2.add("Topic 3");

        List<String> topic3 = new ArrayList<>();
        topic3.add("Topic 1");
        topic3.add("Topic 2");
        topic3.add("Topic 3");

        List<String> topic4 = new ArrayList<>();
        topic4.add("Topic 1");
        topic4.add("Topic 2");
        topic4.add("Topic 3");

        List<String> topic5 = new ArrayList<>();
        topic5.add("Topic 1");
        topic5.add("Topic 2");
        topic5.add("Topic 3");

        topicList.put(chapterList.get(0),topic1);
        topicList.put(chapterList.get(1),topic2);
        topicList.put(chapterList.get(2),topic3);
        topicList.put(chapterList.get(3),topic4);
        topicList.put(chapterList.get(4),topic5);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can visible and unvisible them

Comment: At first set  the recycler view visiblty as gone then make it visible

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove showList() from the onCreate-Method. Instead, find your ImageView by id using `ImageView yourImageView = findViewById(R.id.your_image_view)`. And then add an OnClickListener to yourImageView that calls the `showList()`-method like so:

```
yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showList();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern, to know that I have two activities which are activity_main , the one that created when you have your first app and I have created another activity "main_page" . The code I mentioned above is on the  "Jave activity_main" the first one, which is not now the main show when you run the app it is the second activity. The question do I have to move the code to the second activity because it's the main activity  ?

Comment: I don't quite understand which is the main and which is the second. So when you start the app there is an activity that is shown - let's call that the MainActivity. And then there is a second activity that should contain the button and the ExpandableListView - let's call that ListActivity (I think that is your second activity). The activity that should show the list, should be the one containing the code from my answer.